# Convert Month String to Integer in Java

Tags: java, parsing, datetime

Given a month string such as:

```
    "Feb"
or
    "February"
```

Is there any core Java or third party library functionality that would allow you to convert this string to the corresponding month number in a locale agnostic way?

Comment: are you 100% sure that the given string will always be "Feb" and (e.g) not "Φεβ";

Comment: Have you checked out the Joda date libraries?

Comment: Yes Joda has served me well, but could not find anything in there for parsing a month string to month number.

@cherouvim: I'm not sure I take your meaning, thanks

Comment: cherouvim is asking about internationalization issues, are you sure you are always getting the month in English?

Comment: @Yishai for my use case yes, but still a valid point.. although maybe out of the scope of this question

@dangerstat I looked into the Joda libs a bit more, and Joda does indeed support datetime parsing through the very powerful DateTimeFormat class

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An alternative to SimpleDateFormat using Joda time:

```
    import org.joda.time.DateTime;
    import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
    import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
    ...

    // if default locale is ok simply omit '.withLocale(...)'
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM");
    DateTime instance        = format.withLocale(Locale.FRENCH).parseDateTime("août");  

    int month_number         = instance.getMonthOfYear();
    String month_text        = instance.monthOfYear().getAsText(Locale.ENGLISH);

    System.out.println( "Month Number: " + month_number );
    System.out.println( "Month Text:   " + month_text   );

    OUTPUT:
        Month Number: 8
        Month Text:   August
```

Answer (score 48):

You could parse the month using SimpleDateFormat:

```
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("Feb");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    System.out.println(month == Calendar.FEBRUARY);
```

Be careful comparing `int month` to an int (it does *not* equal 2!). Safest is to compare them using `Calendar`'s static fields (like `Calendar.FEBRUARY`).

Comment: Having looked into joda time, it is more concise, robust, and gives the expected month number.  Is there a reason why SimpleDateFormat should be preferred?  If not I see no reason why not to pick Joda time as the answer... thanks

Comment: The only advantage I can think of is that the SimpleDateFormat doesn't need any 3rd party jar. But if it's all the same to you, I'd go for the (superior) functionality of Joda.

Comment: joda time will effectively be part of core java in v8 with JSR 310

Comment: Or compare with int but return `cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1` as months begin from 0.

Answer (score 12):

Java 8 solution:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM")
                                            .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
TemporalAccessor accessor = parser.parse("Feb");
System.out.println(accessor.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR));  // prints 2
```

Answer (score 3):

you could just set up a switch statment, something like this (below).
I'm posting this in case anyone wants a simple, easy to understand solution
I know I would have wanted it before I typed this up:

```
switch(input2) {
            case "january":
            case "jan":
                input2 = "1";
            break;

            case "febuary":
            case "feb":
                input2 = "2";
            break;

            case "march":
            case "mar":
                input2 = "3";
            break;

            case "april":
            case "apr":
                input2 = "4";
            break;

            case "may":
                input2 = "5";
            break;

            case "june":
            case "jun":
                input2 = "6";
            break;

            case "july":
            case "jul":
                input2 = "7";
            break;

            case "august":
            case "aug":
                input2 = "8";
            break;

            case "september":
            case "sep":
            case "sept":
                input2 = "9";
            break;

            case "october":
            case "oct":
                input2 = "10";
            break;

            case "november":
            case "nov":
                input2 = "11";
            break;

            case "december":
            case "dec":
                input2 = "12";
            break;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

[SimpleDateFormat.parse](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to do it:

```
 String a = "August 10, 2021 10:00 AM";

    SimpleDateFormat fromUser = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");

    SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    String reformattedStr = myFormat.format(fromUser.parse(a));

    System.out.println(reformattedStr); // 08/10/2021
```