# Correct pattern for parsing from String to LocalDateTime format

Tags: java, datetime

I'm trying to parse dates which come in format of "1 March 2019" or eg "15 March 2019" in LocalDateTime format but I'm struggling with finding the correct pattern for it.

I've tried the example with pattern "dd M/L yyyy" and simply "d M/L yyyy" but none seem to work.

```java
String begda = "1 March 2019";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd M/L yyyy");
LocalDateTime ldtBeg = LocalDateTime.parse(begda, formatter);
```

It will just throw an DateTimeParseException stating that it could not get parsed.

Comment: One problem - you need to use LocalDate instead of LocalDateTime because you have no time component.

Comment: Note that "dd" means "zero-padded day of month", which doesn't look like it's what you've got in "1 March 2019".

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I switched to LocalDate and pattern "d MMMM yyyy" which works for me. One important thing to note, which caused additional issues on my end: The parsing of "March" also depends on the locale and there was a mismatch between my testdata and the locale on my computer.

Comment: You misunderstood when the docs said `M/L month-of-year`. It means `M` *or* `L`. You need to read it in conjunction with this: “Pattern letters 'L', 'c', and 'q' specify the stand-alone form of the text styles.” A few locales have separate stand-alone forms of month names. Since you’ve got a full date, you shouldn’t use it here, that is, you should not use `L`, that is, you should use `M`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `MMMM` for the complete month like `March`. And use `d` for day like `1`.

It should like `d MMMM yyyy`.

And specify the [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) for the human language to use in reading the name of month.

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "1 March 2019" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( 
        "d MMMM yyyy",
        Locale.UK
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're doing it wrong

the correct date format for java is `("dd MMMM yyyy")`

and for more information visit [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-date) site

Comment: There are any number of date formats you can use, and Java gives a lot of flexibility for parsing them. There's no such thing as "the correct date format for Java".

Comment: (It's no more correct to claim that using the full month name instead of the zero-padded month number is "the correct date format".)

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for converting String month `MARCH`. So, while parsing you need to mention of which Locale it is.

while formatting this locale is being used and respective month for that is returned.

If you are familiar with Calendar then you can use that as well.
I guess this link can give you some hint

[Convert Month String to Integer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268969/convert-month-string-to-integer-in-java)

Comment: The `Calender` class is poorly designed and long outdated, and also will not help the asker’s problem. Mentioning it here certainly isn’t helpful. Mentioning locale certainly *is* helpful.